# Docx file transfer from server to client using httpwebrequest/httpwebresponse

Tags: c#, http

In C# I've to write code for Docx file send from server application to client application using HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse classes without web browser.

I've worked out with sockets(TCP/IP), its works really fine. But I want to run with http protocol. Here i'm using Apache Tomcat 7 as webserver.

For example: server (application) assigned particular word file to client (application) then client download the assigned file with help of HTTP protocol using apache tomcat web server

Note: I didn't WCF services, I'm using only Windows application .. so tell me in that requirement manner ..

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example;

```
        string myFileName = @"c:\temp\sample.docx";

        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Proxy = null;
            wc.DownloadFile("http://urlhere/Test.docx", myFileName);
        }
```

Comment: Man, i know that'll work pretty good. but i dont need download word file from URI. suppose in sockets "serversocket.send(filename)" to client and "clientsocket.receive(filename)" from server . i want this style in http protocol. i didnt use web browser

Comment: webclient is just a wrapper for httpwebrequest classes, you should be able to use it with a URI in a non-web application.